# Restoration/mod of mid-1960s PP 2xEl844 4x6AT6 guitar amp, voltage, hum problems. Similar to Fender 5F10 schematic

Tags: amplifier, vacuum-tube

Is this the right place to find solutions to the above problems?

I'm trying to make this amp usable, but after some rebuilding and reconfiguring, I still have a hum problem and what seems to be odd voltages.

The current configuration is 2 inputs (one with a treble peaking tweak added,) 4x6AT6 preamp tubes, volume and treble/bass controls after V2, variable NFB added on cathode of V3, V4 cathodyne phase inverter, EL844s V5 and V6 cathode biased, 5Y3GT rect.

I have changed all capacitors with close to same values, added 510 ohm/5W screen resistors.

B+ is 370V on power plates (recommended 250), 320 on screens; and preamp plates V1-4 measure 123,87, 112, 174 (recommended 100V).

How can I tame the voltages and clean up the output?

The heaters are 5.05V and 6.54. There is a filament CT but no secondary HV CT on the transformer.

Comment: As a fellow guitarist I feel your pain. As an electronics engineer (and that is what this site is), you need to post schematics.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I'll try to cobble something together. Meanwhile, it is not a lot different from the Fender 5F10 circuit (early Harvard) <https://is.gd/MZiWoa>, apart from the main differences I mentioned.

Comment: The devil will hide in the details.

Comment: This is the best schematic I can produce for now. Might be errors. My alterations: Fender style input, treble peak on guitar channel, tremolo converted to adjustable NFB with on/off switch on pot, tube converted to preamp stage, line out jack. Note that preamp tubes are triodes, speakers stand in for jacks, bridge rect symbol instead of 5Y3 tube. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B5cn1fZKYQJM-x9YMhEzxS_6jl-IusMo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Note that some odd resistor values are as measured, not according to color code.

Answer (score 1):

If your hum problem is 50 or 100 Hz, my first step should be to remove V4 (of course no power) and check. If no hum, check removing V3 and so on V2 and V1 to find where this noise comes from.
Check heater wires are twisted and as far away as possible from signals, specially in pre-amp.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I'm in Canada, so its 60 or 120 Hz. Trying to whip up a schematic so you have a better idea. I have used shielded cable on the long preamp signal runs, and kept the wires up in the air as far from filaments as possible. I will give your suggestions a try once the schematic is more or less presentable. Can Kicad files be uploaded? By the way, I have just started using a USB oscilloscope, so I could step through the connections with that.

Comment: I should mention that the amp was discovered in a crawl space under a house where it may have lain for 30 years or more. I was surprised that the transformers hadn't shorted. It is made by Lifco, a Montreal firm that produced various cheap electronics devices, from radios to turntables and guitar amps in the 1950s and 1960s. The latter were mainly copies of other brands. (e.g., they did a copy of the Traynor YBA-1) Gut shots are available if anyone is interested.

Comment: For the caps I used what similar value items I had available, and bought a few extras from a local electronics store that has been in business for 61 years. Some of his caps may be about that old too. The owner, in his 80s, remembers doing a few subcontract jobs for Lifco in the 1960s.

Comment: Here's the hum report. Hum not present when volume at zero. Rises in volume as volume increased, 60Hz plus a shrill metallic whistle. Attenuated as more NFB added. Same when V4 removed. Disappears when V3 removed. Could it be the NFB insertion on cathode of V3?

Comment: I think there is a missing groung connection in output transformer secondary winding (opposite to D point).

Comment: Also with NFB potenciometer at low position (lower resistance than 1.5 kohms), bias voltage of V3 is changing. You need a capacitor (same value as V1 and V2: C33 uF) between central point of pot and cathode of V3.

Comment: Another option is to change 10 kohms resistor, and rewired between central point of NFB potenciometer and V3  cathode. In this way, bias voltage will not be modify significantly.

Comment: I have made the correction you suggest at output secondary (the jack is self grounded), and am in the process of rebuilding the tone stack to Fender circuit AA763, with component values according to what I have available.

Comment: With regard to NFB, thank you for your suggestion. I note that the Fender 5F10 circuit does not have a bypass cap. The noise (especially high frequency whistle) is worst when NFB is shut off. I suppose it is worth a try.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not quite understand your second suggestion. Please be aware that I am not a trained technician. You write: "change 10k resistor". To what? Also, "rewire between central point of NFB potentiometer and V3 cathode". Do you mean move the reisistor to a position between pot wiper and V3 cathode? I wonder if the pot should be wired as a variable resistor (from lug 3, not from the wiper as it is now)??

Comment: Yes, I mean move the resistor to a position between pot wiper and V3 cathode. In that way, with pot in minimum position, you have a 10k resistor in paralell with cathode 1.5k. Same influence but not as much as actually.

Comment: Many thanks Bravale. Some further questions, if you don't mind. I can move the 10K resistor to the wiper of the pot. Should I also add a capacitor bypassing the resistor, or bypassing the 1.5K cathode resistor? Also, if the NFB enters on terminal 1 and exits by the wiper, should terminal 3 be grounded? Or should the NFB exit by terminal 3 (making the pot a variable resistor)? I.e., the wiper would not be used in that case.

Comment: It seems to me that if the 10K resistor connects the wiper to the cathode, then when the switched pot is in OFF position, the resistor does not go to ground. Is that a problem?

Comment: It is not necessary the capacitor, as the influence of a 10k resistor regarding a 1.5k is not much. Also don´t bypass cathode 1.5k with a capacitor, that way all audio signal feed back will be grounded --> no feed back.  I think the idea of the pot is to ajust NFB from 0 to 100%, so connect point D to terminal 1 and terminal 3 to ground. If you wire the pot as a variable resistor, you can ajust feed back , but minimum will not be 0% .  Please check G1 of valves EL84, they are floating. There should be a resistor to ground or some negative bias.

Comment: Thank you again for clarifications. After I rebuild the tone stack (point to point gives me headaches) I will test with the NFB configuration you suggest. However, on G1 the schematic is not accurate. There is a 470K grid leak resistor to ground which I forgot to enter. I wonder if it is preferable to use a grid stopper of 1.5K, as is most common on Fender circuits?

Comment: I have completed alterations to the circuit and updated the schematic. I will test tomorrow to see how it performs. Thank you again for your suggestions. Note however that the problem of high voltages remains.

Comment: After alterations the amp does not pass a signal and still produces hum and buzz, only when volume not zero, and volume dependent. It is also attenuated by level of NFB. Removing V3 eliminates the noise. Meanwhile an updated schematic can be found here. <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uaA8_Bl0skomvx7VcaD-BOx1DMcxce4b/view?usp=sharing> Suggestions welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I checked your update diagram. The problem could be a missing resistor in G of V2 to ground. There is no bias, so current is high and this can explain low voltage 82 V on  V2 plate. Also check C11 connections, one terminal should be directly on A1 of V4 (probably this is a diagram mistake).

Comment: Many thanks again for the suggestions. I have corrected the connection of C11 to A1 of V4 on the schematic and will add resistor R29 to the circuit. All I have available is an old 1.2M, so that will have to do. I will report on results later today, time permittting.

Comment: Output very fuzzy and distorted after changes. Note that I replaced shielded cables with regular as I think there was a short to the shielding somewhere. See <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9rdk_xlbbtbdwdHEzqcDXDI0I_TufDG/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: I don´t see more issues in schematics. Check voltages in valves pins,-may be you find something illogical-, and look over for faulty components (a tester for capacitors could help).

Comment: Thanks again for comments. On the recommendation of a friend I pulled all the tubes except U1 (and the rectifier) and checked following grid (U2) with oscilloscope. First stage seems OK, but when I insert U2 and test grid of U2, there is clipping on the top of the wave. Could be a bias problem on U1 or U2? Or plate voltage too high? One correction to the schematic: there is a .02uF cap after plate of U2 and before tone stack.

Comment: The plate current of EC92 valves in this amplifier is about 1 mA. If you measure cathode to ground should be about 1.5 volts. That means the grid is 1.5 volts negative respect the cathode. If your wave positive voltage peak is higher of 1.5 volt, the grid will start conducting (positive respect cathode) and you will see clipping. The cap before tone net is not relevant, as dc component is already blocked by C5, C6 and C7.

Comment: The previous comment apply to U1, U2 and U3, where cathode resistor is 1.5k. Regarding U4, the bias resistor R17 is 3.2k, so signal voltage peak could be up to 3.2 volts.

Comment: THank you again. Actually the preamp tubes are 6AT6, for which plate current should be 0.8ma. If I understand correctly grid voltage should be -1, but can go to zero. I will remove the irrelevant coupling cap. I will do the cathode to ground measurement and report. For 6AT6 specs see <https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/6/6AT6.pdf>

Comment: Here is a link to the schem with correct tube labels. <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f24COayUcJ-uyCj80CLhoHaCBpht5sux/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: Check the pins of these valves, Grid=1, Cathode=2, Plate=7. Unused diodes pin 5 and 6 better connect to ground. The grid voltage to ground will be zero, if you measue grid to cathode you will fin negative 1 volt.

Comment: I just finished a series of measurements on tubes 1-6, all to ground.
Plate Voltage: 136/236/125/188/379/379
Plate current mA: 10/9/9.2/14/27/27
Cathode voltage: 1.35/1/1/2/4/8/8
Grid voltage: 1.6mv/1.4V/.2/23V/10mV/13mv
Will try the measurements you suggest shortly.

Comment: Here are the cathode to grid voltages, all negative, on tubes 1-6: 1.3/0.7/1.1/0.9/7.2/7.2

Comment: Did you checked valves pins?, there is a missmatch in diagrams for U1..U4. Plate voltage are Ok except U2, 236 V is too high. Plate current for U1..U4 are too high, not plausible values for the plate resistors. Cathodes voltages: I see 7 values, probably cathode of U4 is 24 V; if so, it is Ok. About grid voltage to ground, +1.4 V for U2 is not Ok, and does not agree with the measurement grid-cathode of negative 0.7 V. Something is wrong in U2, check pins, test resistors, or swap the valve with another one and check again voltages.

Comment: U1 to U4 are 6AT6 but there is no symbol for this tube in the Kicad library. I tried to edit it but cannot save the edits. On 6AT6 pins are 1-Grid, 2-Cathode, 7-Plate. Pins 3 and 4 are heaters, and 5 and 6 are unused diode plates. On pins 5 and 6 there are no shorts between pins and no continuity to ground. They are not used. I have changed plate resistor on U2 to 260K. I will check further.

Comment: The larger plate resistor on U2 has a small effect. Plate voltage down to 150 from 236, Plate surrent at 12 mA, grid voltage down to 280 mV. But the strong distorted signal persists, with clipping on U2. I wonder if the more sensible approach would be to reduce HV overall with a large 10W resistor on the rectifier output, or in some other way. Also, would it make sense to convert to SS rectification by attaching diodes to the socket pins and removing the tube?

Comment: I wish to thank Bravale and others who have contributed to troubleshooting process. Unfortunately there appears to be no solution as long as U2 is in the circuit. I have tried various strategies: switching the plate resistor and cathode resistor to higher values, placing a local negative feedback loop on U2 and even rewiring all signal lines with coax. The very distorted signal persists, even at lower voltages on the variac.

Comment: My friend the tech with 40+ years of experience in high end audio cannot figure it out either. He could only venture to suggest that there is somehow too much gain in the circuit, or else I have made a big mistake somewhere that is not obvious. Of course I checked the integrity of the socket and switched tubes. If there are no other options, I will simply bypass the U2 socket and probably add a voltage regulator at the power end so that the desired voltage can be dialed in. Thanks again for your efforts.